# How to skip empty lines without string class

Tags: c++

In the following code I can't use the `std::string` class.

I'm trying to read a file that has empty lines, and I want to ignore the empty lines when I encounter them.

I've tested out some ideas using a simplified example and a made-up text file containing empty lines.

```
int main() {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("test.txt");
    if(fin.fail()){
        cout << "Input file fail.";
        exit(-1);
    }

    char line[10];

    while(!fin.eof()){
       fin.getline(line, 10);
       if(line[0] == '\n')
           cout << "skip" << "\n"; 
       else
           cout << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

I've also tried things like `strlen(line) == 1`, but nothing worked so far.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/2069064)

Comment: `std::getline()` discards the delimiter, which explains why neither of your solutions will work.

Comment: *We're not allowed to use the string class*  -- So might as well call your course *C programming* instead of *C++ programming*.

Comment: Teaching C++ while disallowing `std::string` is cruel and unusual. It would be a good idea to encourage your professor to [stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Comment: @Barry Always a good notice when seeing that code, but not relevant for the particular case behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::getline()` already takes care of the `'\n'` character (it will be discarded), `line[0]` would contain `'\0'` in the case of an empty input.

Just compare for `'\0'` instead of `'\n'`:

```
if(line[0] == '\0')
    cout << "skip" << "\n"; 
else
    cout << line << "\n";
```

---

> I've also tried things like `strlen(line) == 1`

If so, shouldn't that have been `strlen(line) == 0` for an ***empty*** line?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code. The first is that your loop isn't correct. You have to check the result of the `getline()` call, not `eof()`. Please see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). That restructured loop becomes:

```
while (fin.getline(line, 10)) {
    ...
}
```

Next, when you read a line with `getline()` (and 10 seems *really* short for a line), the delimiter will not be part of the body. There will not be a `\n` in `line` when you're doing reading. You'll just have an empty string. So the right way to discard empty lines is:

```
while (fin.getline(line, 10)) {
    if (line[0]) {
        // we have contents!
    }
}
```

Or really, `std::string` is just way better:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
    if (!line.empty()) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline()` discards the delimiter `\n`. But you might also want to consider that on some systems lines may be delimited by `\r\n`.

Comment: `std::getline()` discards `\r\n` as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Does it also if you transfer files between different systems?